# android set linearlayout horizontal gap?

Tags: android

i added a lot of images into a linearlayout with horizontal orientation.

now i wanna set a gap between each image , is that possible??

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, add this to each of the `ImageViews`:

```
android:layout_mariginRight="10px"
```